# How to find the last commits that were pushed on a branch since the prior push?

Tags: git

Using `git log --name-status` gives all the commits on that branch.

Using `git log -1 --name-status` gives only the last commit.

I want to get the last commits that were in the last push. Even knowing how many commits there were in the last push would help me because I can parametrize the command with `-n`.

The answer at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439741/libgit2sharp-get-all-commits-since-the-last-push) does not help me. Using `git whatchanged` does not help me too much either.

Comment: `> log.txt` seems irrelevant for your question, please remove it by editing your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the ID of the last push in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653318/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-the-last-push-in-git)

Comment: `git log origin/master..`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+last+push

Answer (score 3):

Just add `--remotes` at the end of your command line, like:

```
 git log -1 --name-status --remotes
```